# how to justify content start if line is not full

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I have array map with buttons. now i want the container stay like now (in the center) but when new row not full i want the items go start (right now its in the center also)
how can I handle this?(see image below)

my component code:

```
const AvailableHours = ({ avHoursInDay }) => {
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        {avHoursInDay.map((item, i) => {
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity key={i} style={styles.button} onPress={console.log("s")}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>{item.time}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            );
        })}
    </View>
   );
   }  ;

   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    justifyContent: "center",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "red",
},
text: {
    color: "white",
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    paddingVertical: 6,
    fontSize: 16,
    fontFamily: "heebo",
    textAlign: "center",
},
button: {
    margin: 2,
    borderRadius: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    borderColor: "#d9b310",
},
```

image with the problem:
[image: image with the problem:]

image for what I want to achieve:
[image: image for what I want to achieve:]

Answer (score 2):

I just modified some of your code give it s try and let me know if it helps.

```
const AvailableHours = ({ avHoursInDay }) => {
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        {avHoursInDay.map((item, i) => {
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity key={i} style={styles.button} onPress={console.log("s")}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>{item.time}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            );
        })}
    </View>
   );
   }  ;

   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "red",
},
text: {
    color: "white",
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    paddingVertical: 6,
    fontSize: 16,
    fontFamily: "heebo",
    textAlign: "center",
},
button: {
    margin: 2,
    borderRadius: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    borderColor: "#d9b310",
},
```

Comment: now all my container is start from the right side... its not what i asked for

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply `align-self: 'flex-start'` on the desired element.

```js
button: {
    margin: 2,
    borderRadius: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    borderColor: "#d9b310",
    align-self: 'flex-start'
},
```